# Read the first word from the text file, find out it's length and count how many words of that length there are in the file

Tags: c, file-io

I'm just a beginner and I have no clue how to get started on this assignment. I had some ideas, while I tried to google the problem, but all of them seemed too complicated for me to successfully make. Any help would be appreciated. By the way I am programming in C language.

Comment: Are you using C or C#? You said C, but tagged your question C#.

Comment: C != C#, what are you actually using?

Comment: please change the tag to C then. Nevermind, I did it (didn't know I had this privilege, I feel strong)

Comment: Please put at least some investigation efforts in your question, it is way too basic.

Comment: Too basic for you. Too advanced for me. I wouldnt ask for help here, if I hadn't tried to do it myself.

Comment: A key skill for programming (in any language or field) is breaking down a big complicated problem you can't begin to tackle into a series of smaller, simpler problems you can.  That's what Nim's answer is showing you. As with most skills, it improves with practise.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a set of tasks which may help you solve your problem yourself.

1. Try to open/close a file in c. Search for "How to open a file in C"
2. Try to read from a file in c. Search for "How to read a text file in C"
3. Now that you know how to open and read a file. Try to open the file, and print out word by word what is in the file. Hints, you'll need to loop, and possibly tokenize.
4. Try to determine the length of a word (a string in c). Search for "Calculate string length in c" (there is a standard function you can use for this)
5. As you read each word (from step 3), print out the length next to it. Search for "how to print formatted output c"
6. Now you have each word in the file and it's length. All you need to do is to get the length of the first word, and instead of printing out all the other words which have the same length, simply count. And at the end, print it out.

Comment: Just to add: Reading word from file can be done with `scanf("%s")`, if we are allowed to assume the length of the word.

Answer (score 0):

There is really simple way to do this. Here is it:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\TestFolder\FromThisFileWeRead.txt");
\\you should be carefull, because if file is not exists, you will have an exeption
\\try to catch it your own way

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                string[] words = text.Split(new char[] {',', ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r'});
                \\separators depend on your text file

                int firstWordLength = words[0].Length;
                int countWordsTheSameLength = 0;

                foreach (string word in words)
                {
                    if(word.Length == firstWordLength)
                    {
                        countWordsTheSameLength++;
                    }
                }
```

The other way similar to previous:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\TestFolder\FromThisFileWeRead.txt");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                int firstWordLength = words[0].Length;
                string[] words = text.Split(new char[] {',', ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r'});
                List<string> wordsList = new List<string>(words);
                int firstWordLength = words[0].Length;
                countWordsTheSameLength = wordsList.FindAll(word => word.Length == firstWordLength).Count;
}
```

For both cases you need to using `System.IO`.

I think it's easy to understand. In future you should try FileStream, StreamRead and StreamWrite classes.

Good luck!